# Training Tesseract for Urdu language

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to train Tesseract for Urdu language. I have installed Tesseract 4.00 and have a representative dataset for Urdu available. I have dataset with images like the one attached:

[Training Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fNXH.png)

I have the label for each image e.g the label for the above image is:

بعد نجی ٹی وی سے گفتگو کرتے ہوئے وزیر خارجہ شاہ محمود قریشی نے بتایا کہ ملاقات

Images are in these fonts: Pak Nastaleeq, Alvi Nastaleeq, Jameel Noori Nastaleeq, Nafees Nastaleeq.

What is the process of training tesseract? How do I tag (make boxes around Urdu word) each Urdu word in the images?